# Overriding the clone method - not working (Java)

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy

I'm writing a search algorithm to solve the 15 puzzle problem in java.
When I clone the puzzle states to generate the new possible moves (the daughters) they still alter each other rather than being separate.

Here's my clone method:

```
public FifteenPuzzleState clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
FifteenPuzzleState copy = (FifteenPuzzleState)super.clone();
for(int i=0; i<copy.currentConfig.length; i++){
    copy.currentConfig[i] = Arrays.copyOf(currentConfig[i], currentConfig[i].length);
}
return copy;     
}
```

So my problem is that after I clone the state and then alter it, it will also affect the previous state and all other clones.
My first thought was that I didn't create a deep copy of the 2d array properly but I can't find anything wrong with the code above.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What part of the object is affected by the altering of a clone? There's no auto deep-copying so you'll need to make sure you clone everything.

Comment: If you want a deep clone, you have to take care of that yourself, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.  You need to make a deep copy by manually `clone()`ing each element in the array.